# Enumerate through words in String with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

The iOS SDK provides a String API

```
func enumerateSubstrings<R>(in range: R, options opts: String.EnumerationOptions = [], _ body: @escaping (String?, Range<String.Index>, Range<String.Index>, inout Bool) -> Void) where R : RangeExpression, R.Bound == String.Index
```

One of the options is `.byWords` which allows you to enumerate through the words in the String. You can also use `.reverse` to enumerate backwards.

I have a need to do this in Android as well. The use case is to extract a substring in a larger string and add `x` number of words before it and `y` number of words after it. For example, given `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.` and the phrase `do eiusmod tempor incididunt`, where `x = 1` and `y = 2`, create the resulting string `sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore`.

So far I’m extracting the matching range and now I’m wondering how to get words.

```
var match = this.removeRange(0, this.indexOf(phrase, 0, true))
match = match.removeRange(phrase.length, match.length)
```

Comment: What is your definition of "word"?

Comment: `BreakIterator`

Comment: `BreakIterator` looks like what I need thanks!

Comment: sure, your welcome